# Restore webview scroll position?

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I want to **save the state** of my `webView` with its **page scroll position** when user leaves the app and restore them when user opens the app again. So that, user can continue reading the restored webview content scrolled down to the restored position.

Here are methods I'm using:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
    webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int positionY = Math.round(scrollPos);
        webView.scrollTo(0, positionY);
    } esle {
      //do something
    }
```

Function that calculates the position:

```
    private int calculateProgression(WebView content) {
    int positionTopView = content.getTop();
    int contentHeight = content.getContentHeight();
    int currentScrollPosition = content.getScrollY();
    int percentWebview = (currentScrollPosition - positionTopView) / contentHeight;
    return percentWebview;
}
```

save/restore functions:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("position", calculateProgression(webView));
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    scrollPos = savedInstanceState.getFloat("position");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the position in the [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in the `OnDestroy` method and retrieve it in the `OnCreate` method.

**EDIT**: As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29), `OnPause` should be the place to store data, not `OnDestroy`.

Comment: sorry but it does not help ,, because when user swips the app from recent apps it does not call onDestroy method !!!!!

Comment: Post your onDestroy method, anyway, you could save it in OnStop, as OnDestroy may be not been called.

Comment: I used onStop() and it works to save the position in a float variable..