# Android WebView Video after closing fullscreen view, webview auto scrolls

Tags: android, html, webview, html5-video

I am using `WebView` to display a webpage having text as well as video content.

It loads & display video correctly as expected.

But when I go to full screen view of video ( I implemeted full screen video view as given [**here**](https://github.com/akhgupta/WebviewVideo) ) and then come back to `WebView`, `WebView` autoscroll in some amount.

How can I fix that?

Please suggest some idea/link.

Comment: show xml code please!

Comment: Which target SDK are you using? I tested the example you pointed out on SDK 24 (Android N) and I couldn't see the auto-scroll issue.

Comment: Please provide some of the code of your xml. where you created webview

Comment: I didnt find the issue, If you want to restore your scrolling then you can check this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020820/restore-webview-scroll-position

Comment: I did it by storing scroll position of webpage before going to FullScreen using JavaScript & then after coming back From FullScreen scroll the page to position stored (Both storing scroll position and scrolling to position stored are being done using JavaScript).

Comment: @RKS can you please share your js?

Comment: got same issue, solwed another way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473138/webview-after-closing-fullscreen-view-webview-auto-scrolls-to-top

Answer (score 1):

I am using a compatible ScrollChangedListener already. So I've decided to scroll the view back in this listener during a period after onHideCustomView.

webview:

```
public interface OnScrollChangedListener {
    void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY);
}

    public void SafeScrollTo(int x, int y) {
        OnScrollChangedListener mScrollChanged = mOnScrollChangeListener;
        mOnScrollChangeListener =null;
        scrollTo(x, y);
        mOnScrollChangeListener =mScrollChanged;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if(mOnScrollChangeListener !=null)
            mOnScrollChangeListener.onScrollChange(this,l,t,oldl,oldt);
    }

    public void setOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener onSrollChangedListener) {
        mOnScrollChangeListener =onSrollChangedListener;
    }

    OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangeListener;
```

Activity:

```
mWebview.setOnScrollChangedListener((v, x, y, oldx, oldy) -> {
                ArticleWebView webview = (ArticleWebView) v;
                if(CustomViewHideTime>0 && System.currentTimeMillis()-CustomViewHideTime<350){
                    webview.SafeScrollTo(oldx, oldy);
                    return;
                }});
```

WebChromeClient:

```
        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            CustomViewHideTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //todo delay and set CustomViewHideTime to 0
        }
```

This can work just fine.

Comment: This solution has one issue, is that `CustomViewHideTime` it must be declared final in order to be used inside `onHideCustomeView`. How do you solve that?