# WebView after closing fullscreen view, webview auto scrolls to top

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, html5-fullscreen

I have `webveiw` *([with fullscreen support](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView))* on the fragment. 
The issue is when i close fullscreen the webview scrolls it position to top. 
Noticed:

- the issue appears only if apply `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flag *(but i need to apply it to have real fullscreen)*
- found [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331940/android-webview-video-after-closing-fullscreen-view-webview-auto-scrolls) is to use java script, but there is no answer. Also i'm not found the way to resolve this with webview functions like `scrollTo` and ect
- when i add *(instesad of fullscreen-view)* view with small size *(100dp height)* i see that webview content is gone. Is it cached somwhere? Is it possible to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the issue was that `webview` have `match_perent or wrap_content` in height and after applying `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` webview lose it height.
solution was to set `layoutParams.height = height` before set `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`

so, in this case "layoutParams.height" - layout height settings, "height" - current view height